# For Chrome extension, I get error when calling http site from https site

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, https, xmlhttprequest, mixed-content

Get error:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https:xxx' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://127.0.0.1/xxx'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

and

Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://127.0.0.1/xxx'.

Two weeks ago, I can run this extension successfully. I don't know why it doesn't work suddenly.

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explanatory; you cannot create requests for http content on https sites due to [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

You will need to either change the https site to http, or vice versa.